# Error en la petición del web sevice soap en android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al mandar los datos al web service soap por que no lo manda y me responde con un null me podrían ayudar por favor

```
  import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Webservice extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://datos/";
    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.73:7001/Ejemplo-Datos-context-root/HolaPort?WSDL";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "nombre";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://datos/nombre";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.webservice);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo nombre = new PropertyInfo();
        nombre.setName("nombre");
        nombre.setValue("f");
        request.addProperty(nombre);
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+request);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{

            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, sobre);
            System.out.println("Evelopen: "+sobre.bodyIn);
            if (transporte!=null) {
                System.out.println("Transporte SI");
            }
            else{System.out.println("Error en el Transporte");}
            SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();
            Log.i("Resultado", resultado.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error1 "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error2 "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Respuesta de código

```
12/23 09:20:17: Launching app
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.dell_dti.datos/lib
I/System.out: Nombre: nombre{nombre=f; }
Hot swapped changes, activity restarted
I/System.out: Evelopen: nombreResponse{return=Holanull; }
I/System.out: Transporte SI
I/Resultado: Holanull
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.785ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2072(467KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(300KB) LOS objects, 37% free, 1557KB/2MB, paused 7.626ms total 24.153ms
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaebb31b0
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaebb31b0
```

Mi web service soap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]